# How to succesfully save a json object recieved as POST- ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, csrf, survey

I'm trying to create an app that allows user to submit reviews.

I used survey.js which returns a json object with the responses, here is the coffee script file which sends the request to the desired url:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: "/surveys/save",
  data: survey.data,
  success: alert("saved"),
  dataType: JSON
```

And in my Controller I try to save the appropriate parameters:

```
def create
    if validate_user
      @submission = Submission.new(submission_params)
      if @submission.save
        redirect_to '/surveys/saved'
      else
        redirect_to '/surveys/nosaved'
      end
    end
end
```

However I see this output from the server:

```
"Started POST "/surveys/save" for ::1 at 2016-08-01 00:21:47 -0400
Processing by SurveysController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"question1"=>"eh", "question2"=>"1", "question3"=>"3", "question4"=>"1", "question5"=>"1", "question6"=>"3", "question7"=>"4", "question8"=>"1", "question9"=>"2", "question10"=>"1"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"
```

Please advise, from my research it seems that I need to prepend the authenticity token to my request but i'm not sure how to go about that.

Thanks!

****UPDATE**

I do have the CSRF meta tag in my application layout file

******UPDATE 2*******

I tried the following in the Coffee script, it resulted in the same output.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  beforeSend: test = (xhr)-> return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf token"]').attr('content'))
  url: "/surveys/save",
  data: survey.data,
  success: alert("saved"),
  dataType: JSON


  });
```

Comment: can you verify if you have this line: `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` somewhere in your layout file eg `application.html.erb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as Abid attempted to do, but by just declaring the header as such in the coffee script.

```
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf token"]').attr('content')},
    url: "/surveys/save",
    data: survey.data,
    success: alert("saved"),
    dataType: JSON
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Below steps will do the trick for you.

1. Make sure you have the csrf_meta tag in your application layout file.
2. Add beforeSend to all ajax requet to set header like below.

   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf token"]').attr('content'));
     },
     url: "/surveys/save",
     data: survey.data,
     dataType: JSON,
     success: alert("saved")
   });

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems like thats what I want to do but I believe your edits were Javascript, I tried the following using a js2coffee script converter Im afraid nothing whatsoever happened, server did not spit out any message when submit was sent.

`$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  beforeSend: setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf token"]').attr('content'))
  url: "/surveys/save",
  data: survey.data,
  success: alert("saved"),
  dataType: JSON


  });`